# How do I cancel a ongoing GET request with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an inputfield, onChange it sends my value of the inputfield to an API. So, the api will start fetching all the data. but when I continue typing again, I want that previous request to be canceled.

I'm using axios for making my request and tried looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) but I can't seem to figure out how it really works, can someone explain how to do this?

Here is my function that gets called by every new input:

```
const onChange = (value) => {
  setTimeout(async() => {
    let result = []

    if (y === "keyword") result = await AutoSuggestionKeyword({
      value: value
    });
    
    else {
      const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
      const source = CancelToken.source();

      await axios.get(`https://${api_uri}/${value.toLowerCase()}`)
        .catch(function(thrown) {
          if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
            console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
          } else {
            // handle error
          }

        }).then(resp => {
          console.log(resp)
        });
      source.cancel();
    }
  }, 500)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a `cancelToken` in your request,

```
axios.get(`https://${api_uri}/${value.toLowerCase()}`, {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).catch(function(thrown) {
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do i put the ```source.cancel();``` .

Comment: @Yorbjörn that can be anywhere, if you have another user action that cancels the request, you can call `source.cancel()` in that event listener as long as `source` is available there.

Comment: So, let's say when I type in my inputfield, my previous request must be cancelled and a new request should be made. I tried doing this ```<input onChange={(e) => { getDataFunction(e.target.value); source.cancel() }/>``` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Scratch the comment above, I managed to get it working, I owe you bigtime! muchas gracias!

Comment: For those who are wondering, problem was that source.cancel() and getDataFunction() was excecuting at the same time, solved it with setting a timeout on the source.cancel()

Comment: @Yorbjörn You're welcome! sorry couldn't get back to your earlier comments, glad you figured it out though :D

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I don't think you can cancel an HTTP request</strike>, but what you can do is wrap it in debounce function, debounce function wait for a certain time before calling the callback or function you wrap or pass on it.

you can simply google debounce and it will give you articles or npm packages that you can use.

I think this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) also has the same issue you are trying to resolve

Happy coding

Edit 1: yeah so you can cancel the http request see comment below

Comment: Axios added support for request cancellation post 0.15 - https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation